# Fancybox iframe does not appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox

**HTML**

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/L9szn1QQfas">Youtube (iframe)</a>
```

This code line works but I want to add dynamically javascript code.

**JS**

```
'<li>' +
'<div class="list-left">' +
'<img src="' + thumb + '">' +
'</div>' +
'<div class="list-right">' +
'<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoID + '"><h3>' + title + '</h3></a>' +
'<small>By <span class="Title">' + channelTitle + '</span> on ' + videoDate + '</small>' +
'<p>' + description + '</p>' +
'</div>' +
'</li>' +
'<div class="clearfix"></div>' +
'';
```

When I clicked the link, I can't open with fancybox. It's open with new page and console says

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/OFMSUI7PAS8'
was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 
'http://www.youtube.com/favicon.ico'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

Comment: Try changing your `href` to be `https` instead of `http`

Comment: Try to change `youtube` link to another, for example `google.com` and tell us if everything work fine

Comment: After changing to `google`, the `console error message` changed?

Comment: Console error message gone. Now I get `GET http://google.com/embed/mUP0tx7Ib2w 404 (Not Found)` error apparently.

Comment: No, I mean change entire `href` with `www.google.com`, replace `<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoID + '"><h3>' + title + '</h3></a>` with `<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="www.google.com"><h3>' + title + '</h3></a>` and report the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

I just used your `pen` and everything worked fine for me, you forgot to pass `type: 'iframe'` to `fancybox`, also you should put your js code in js section in `codepen`, here is screenshot

[image]

And here is the codepen's link: [Click me](http://codepen.io/m-dehghani/pen/xOaQNB)

Comment: @KaanKaraca I just updated the `jsfiddle` link. please check it out.

Comment: Yes, jsfiddle link works but still not working. I uploaded to GitHub. Can you check it?https://github.com/h4yfans/Projects-in-JavaScript/tree/master/Search%20Vidz%20Youtube Look at `getOutput` function

Comment: @KaanKaraca the github doesn't help, could you provide jsfiddle link?

Comment: http://codepen.io/h4yfans/pen/vKzQLP. I use codepen and same problem here. I won't open with fancybox.

Comment: Finally, it works. Thank you!! BTW I want your bookmarks.LOL :)

Comment: xD, feel free to make your own ;), btw if you got the answer, mark it as answer, for helping future readers.